# Function definition changes the outward behavior of <>

Tags: perl, stdin

**IMPORTANT:** The motivation for this question is not to solve a problem, but to understand Perl's behavior.

---

Consider the following toy script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;

sub main {

  @ARGV >= 2 or die "$0: not enough arguments\n";

  my $arg_a = shift @ARGV;
  my $arg_b = shift @ARGV;

  while ( <> ) {
    print "+++ $_";
  }
}

main();

__END__
```

This script takes 2 or more arguments (which it doesn't use).  All it does is to echo (with a `+++` prefix) either its standard input or the contents of however many files are specified as its third, fourth, etc., arguments.

So far the code behaves as I expect it to.

Now consider this slightly modified version:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;

sub slurp {
  local $/ = undef;
  local @ARGV = @_;
  return <>;
}

sub main {

  @ARGV >= 2 or die "$0: not enough arguments\n";

  my $arg_a = shift @ARGV;
  my $arg_b = shift @ARGV;

  my $content = slurp( $arg_a );

  while ( <> ) {
    print "+++ $_";
  }
}

main();

__END__
```

This version of the script does not ignore its first argument; rather, it interprets as the path to a file, and reads its contents into the variable `$content` (which it subsequently ignores).  Other than this, the script should behave exactly as before.

Unfortunately, this version of the script no longer echoes its stdin (though it still does echo the contents of its 3rd, 4th, etc. arguments).

I know that the problem has to do with the way the `slurp` function is implemented, because if I change this implementation to

```
sub slurp {
  local $/ = undef;
  open my $input, $_[ 0 ] or die "$!";
  return <$input>;
}
```

...then the script once more echoes its stdin, when available.

I would like to understand why the first version of `slurp` causes the script to stop working as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to exhaust the iterator (by calling it until it returns `undef`) before it considers using STDIN again.

```
sub slurp {
   local $/ = undef;
   local @ARGV = @_;
   my $rv = <>;   # Read file specified by $_[0].
   1 while <>;    # Exhaust the iterator.
   return $rv;
}
```

or

```
sub slurp {
   local $/ = undef;
   local @ARGV = @_;
   my $rv = "";
   while (my $file = <>) {
      $rv .= $file;
   }

   return $rv;  # Concatenation of all files specified by @_.
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  Adding `1 while <>;` to `slurp` restored the desired behavior.  It is still somewhat startling, because it suggests that the localization of `@ARGV` in `slurp` is not perfect.  Its effects "leak", to affect external code...

Comment: @kjo It is not [@ARGV](https://perldoc.pl/variables/@ARGV) that "leaks", but the [ARGV](https://perldoc.pl/variables/ARGV) magic (global) handle that an empty readline operator makes use of. All handles keep their state within and `ARGV` has additional state as to which file it is iterating through (represented by [$ARGV](https://perldoc.pl/variables/$ARGV)). When you return without getting to eof, it maintains its state, and it only uses `STDIN` if it *starts* with an empty `@ARGV`.

Comment: @Grinnz: thank you for those observations!  They spurred further experimentation.  I discovered that adding `local *ARGV;` to the definition of `slurp` obviates the need to exhaust the iterator with `1 while <>`...

Comment: Interesting! I would not have anticipated that outcome.

Comment: @ikegami: as a further wrinkle, the `local *ARGV` must happen before the `local @ARGV`.

Comment: Yes, because `*ARGV` (the symbol table entry for variables named `ARGV`) contains `$ARGV` (`${ *ARGV{SCALAR} }`), `@ARGV` (`@{ *ARGV{ARRAY} }`), etc in addition to `*ARGV{IO}` (the file handle). You could try the more targetted `local *ARGV{IO};`, but I don't know if you can localize glob slots.

Comment: @ikegami: `local *ARGV{IO}` resulted in an error, but I'm happy with `local *ARGV`; as you noted, it renders the `local @ARGV` unnecessary.

Comment: Not surprised, but thanks for letting me know. And not just `@ARGV`; it's good to localize `$ARGV` too. So yeah, it's a good way to go.

Answer (score 1):

For `<>` to work with `STDIN` it has to be called when `@ARGV` is  empty. If there are filenames in `@ARGV` when `<>` is run they are removed from there as files are read, and then you'd *need to call `<>` again* in order to wait for the `STDIN`.

```
perl -wE'if (@ARGV) { print while <> }; print while <>' file
```

It is the second `print while <>` that waits on `STDIN` (without it `file` is printed and program exits).

That could in principle happen with your sub, if it were to read all files from `@ARGV` and once the control is back at the `<>` invocation in the main that one would then wait for `STDIN`.

However, your sub *localizes* the `@ARGV` (good practice!), so once it exits the global `@ARGV` still has what it did in the beginning.<sup>†</sup> Then `while` in the main reads those files (again), gets that one `undef` that it is due at the end of the last file, and exits.

One way to see this: remove all from `@ARGV` after the sub that reads input is called and before the `while` in main,. Then that `while` will wait for `STDIN` again, regardless of the sub. Like

```
perl -wE'
    sub ri { local @ARGV = @_; return <> }; 
    print for ri(@ARGV); 
    say"argv: @ARGV";
    @ARGV=(); 
    print while <>
' file
```

(A detail to note is that your example seems to take two files while the sub deals with one, so even if the sub were to use the global `@ARGV` (not `local`-ized) and remove a file from `@ARGV`, there'd still be one file left there to occupy the `while` in the main.  So you still wouldn't get `STDIN`.)

Another way to see all this: add another `print while <>`, at the end; *that* one will wait on `STDIN`.

This is all described in [I/O Operators (perlop)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I%2fO-Operators), albeit it requires quite close reading.

---

<sup>†</sup> On `local $GLOBAL_VAR;` the value of `$GLOBAL_VAR` is copied away, and it gets restored as that scope is exited. So [local](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/local.html) protects the global variable from changes, within its scope.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't see how the scripts can differ in the number of elements in `@ARGV`.  AFAICT, whenever the script is called with exactly two arguments, `@ARGV` will be empty by the time the `while ( <> ) {` line is executed, regardless of which version of the script I'm referring to.

Comment: @kjo  Did you try the second "one"-liner?  Or, add to your script `say "@ARGV";` after you call the sub.  The sub doesn't empty the `@ARGV`, since it (nicely!) uses its (`local`) copy.   Thus the `while` in the main has filenames in `@ARGV` and that's what it does (prints those files); it never gets to `STDIN`. Another way to see this: add another `print while <>;`, at the end of your script.  Then _that_ one will wait at `STDIN`.  (These are some of the things I did here for testing.) And try the one-liners I posted.